# How to read an MPS file for scipy milp

Tags: python, scipy

Scipy 1.9 now supports [milp](https://scipy.github.io/devdocs/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.milp.html#scipy.optimize.milp). This is great news but to use it I need to read in an [MPS](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPS_(format)) file specifying the problem. Scipy doesn't seem to have a function to read in MPS files.

How can I do that?

Comment: [Unfortunately, It's not implemented yet](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/14593). But it's still on my to-do list...

Comment: @joni Thank you. Is there a workaround in the meantime?

Comment: Yes, I'll post it as an answer later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, this feature is not implemented yet. As a workaround, you could read the .mps file with a modelling framework like [PuLP](https://coin-or.github.io/pulp/) or [python-mip](https://github.com/coin-or/python-mip) and then extract all the data of the underlying MILP.

Here's a naïve (and thus slow) implementation of this approach by means of python-mip:

```py
import numpy as np
from mip import Model
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix

def read_mps(file: str):
    """
    Reads a .mps and saves all the data of the MILP:

    min c^T * x

    s.t. b_l <= A*x <= b_u
          lb <=   x <= ub
                x_i integer if integrality[i] = 1
    """
    mdl = Model(solver_name="CBC")
    mdl.read(file)

    # model parameters
    num_vars = len(mdl.vars)
    num_cons = len(mdl.constrs)

    # variable types and bounds
    lb = np.zeros(num_vars)
    ub = np.inf*np.ones(num_vars)
    integrality = np.zeros(num_vars)
    for i, var in enumerate(mdl.vars):
        lb[i] = var.lb
        ub[i] = var.ub
        if var.var_type != "C":
            integrality[i] = 1

    # objective
    c = np.zeros(num_vars)
    for i, var in enumerate(mdl.vars):
        if var in mdl.objective.expr:
            c[i] = mdl.objective.expr[var]
    if mdl.sense != "MIN":
        c *= -1.0

    # constraint coefficient matrix
    b_l = -np.inf*np.ones((num_cons))
    b_u = np.inf*np.ones((num_cons))
    row_ind = []
    col_ind = []
    data    = []
    for i, con in enumerate(mdl.constrs):
        if con.expr.sense == "=":
            b_l[i] = con.rhs
            b_u[i] = con.rhs
        elif con.expr.sense == "<":
            b_u[i] = con.rhs
        elif con.expr.sense == ">":
            b_l[i] = con.rhs
        for j, var in enumerate(mdl.vars):
            if var in (expr := con.expr.expr):
                coeff = expr[var]
                row_ind.append(i)
                col_ind.append(j)
                data.append(coeff)
    A = csr_matrix((data, (row_ind, col_ind)), shape=(num_cons, num_vars))
    return c, b_l, A, b_u, lb, ub, integrality
```

Then, you can read all the data and pass it to `milp` like this:

```py
from scipy.optimize import milp, Bounds, LinearConstraint

c, b_l, A, b_u, lb, ub, integrality = read_mps("example.mps")
bounds = Bounds(lb, ub)
constraints = LinearConstraint(A, b_l, b_u)

res = milp(c=c, constraints=constraints, bounds=bounds, integrality=integrality)
```

Having said this, the above workaround is only useful for small to mid-sized model files.

By the way, it's worth mentioning that `scipy.optimize.milp` uses the [HiGHS solver](https://highs.dev/) under the hood, for which an interface was also recently built into PuLP and there are plans to do the same for python-mip. Both modelling frameworks can read .lp and .mps files and pass them to the interfaced solvers, so there's no urgent need to wait for this feature in scipy. However, to be fair, PuLP only interfaces the executables of some solvers instead of shipping them with the python package and further assumes the end-user has them already installed. IMO, this isn't really a convenient approach.

Comment: Thank you. If you wanted to read in a larger model is PuLP the way to go?